# Assign array element to variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, variables, assign

I know this is a silly question, but i'm stucked!
I have the following array:

```
Array ( [type] => 8 [message] => Use of undefined constant hola - assumed 'hola' 
 [file] => C:\wamp\www\WeCode\code.php(29) : eval()'d code [line] => 3 )
```

I want a variable `$var` to have the string of [message] element. I'm trying to access the array via indexes, but it throws me offset errors! So what can I do? I think is pretty simple, but I'm stuck with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
$var = $array['message'];
```

In this case, `message` is your array index.

Comment: In case it is a scalar array you can do $var_scalar = $array['0'];

Answer (score 0):

It's an associative array and you need to access elements by key. In your case:

```
$var = $array['message'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your array syntax is correct, but I like to create associative arrays this way:

```
$array1 = array( 'type' => 8, 'message' => "Use of undefined constant hola - assumed 'hola'", 'file' => "C:\wamp\www\WeCode\code.php(29) : eval()'d code", 'line' => 3 );
```

Then since this is an associative array, you can access it like this:

```
$var2 = $array1['message'];
```

Comment: Please do not recommend things like `$arr[key]`. This is not future-proof and bad style.

Comment: Ok, the last code is what I needed, nothing else.
Thanks, Revent.

Answer (score 0):

`list($var1,$var2)=$array`

Like `array()`, this is not really a function, but a language construct. `list()` is used to assign a list of variables in one operation. Strings can not be unpacked and `list()` expressions can not be completely empty.