# Assign Array Value to Variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I thought this was an easy task, but apparently not.

```
   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->loadHTMLFile("myhtml.html");
   $timestamp = $dom->getElementById('timestamp');
   $timestamp = $dom->saveHTML($timestamp);
   $matches_out = array();
   if (preg_match_all('/<div id="timestamp">(.*)<\/div>/', $timestamp, $matches_out)) {
  $timestamp = $matches_out[0];
  }
  echo $timestamp;
```

I need to get the value out of the array and store it in the `$timestamp` variable. When I use `print_r()` I get `Array ( [0] =>1422936994)`. I thought that mean to get my timestamp I just do `$matches_out[0]` because I can see it right there on the zero index, or am I missing something.

Trying to echo it out gets me this: `Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\myscript.php on line 10`

Comment: i dont really understand the question, but yes, $timestamps is now array, when you do echo, it will display the error

Comment: but I thought you could get a string from an array using the index number, see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16876209

Comment: if you look at preg_match_all() documentation, then you will realize that $matches_out is Array of all matches in multi-dimensional array ordered according to flags. so please do not expect $matches_out[0] is string now

Comment: I don't understand why you even want to use `preg_match_all`. Why not use the [DOMDocument object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) methods? For example the [getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$matches_out` is multi-dimensional array. So your correct code would be something like `$matches_out[0][0]`. Please inspect your array again to make sure you get the correct value.

See [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Comment: How do I store this value in a variable not merely for echoing but for performing mathematical operations on?

Comment: Please use $var_name = $matches_out[0][0];

Answer (score 1):

$timestamp is an array.
So instead of

```
echo $timestamp;
```

do

```
echo $timestamp[0];
```

And once again if you don't want to have indexes:

```
$newTimestamp = $timestamp[0];
echo $newTimestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the wrong item, timestamp the variable has become an array
call it the same way like this

```
$timestamp[0]
```

Comment: is there a way to assign that, $timestamp[0] to an actual variable so I can avoid using index numbers...? Or if I want to say, perform a mathematical operation on the timestamp do I have to use,

`$myResult = $timestamp[0] - 100;`

because the above just gets me `-100`